# pandasで複数のCSVから特定行のみを抽出してCSVにしたい

Tags: python, pandas

pythonを使いはじめて２週間になります。
やりたいことは以下です。

①pandasを使って複数のCSVを読みこんで２行目のみをそれぞれから抽出
②１つ目のCSVから抽出した行は１行目
　２つ目のCSVから抽出した行は２行目・・・
と、いうふうにしたいのですが、
→できたことは
・フォルダにあるCSVを読み込む
→あいまいorわからない
・なんとなく２行目もとりだせている気もするんですが。
・結合のしかたがわかりません。
・CSVに書き出しできたんですが、１個しか抽出できていなく、行列ひっくりかえっています。なぜですか？

CSVは全部で１２０個
１０３行×１０３列の数字がはいっています。
いきなり１２０個でためすのも怖いのでまずは２個からやってみています。

どうしたらよいか教えてください。

[image: プログラムです]

Answer (score 2):

多分こんな感じで動作するかと思います。

```
dfs = []
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
    dfs.append(df.iloc[[1]])
merged_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
merged_df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

> なんとなく２行目もとりだせている気もするんですが。

とりあえず２行目データは `df.iloc[1]` にて取り出すことが出来るのですが、 `df.iloc[1]` の場合、戻り値は Series型 (一次元データ)となります。今回は DataFame型のまま行データとして取り出した方が都合がよいので `df.iloc[[1]]` とするほうが良いかと思います。

> 結合のしかたがわかりません。

結合は質問のコードにコメントアウトで書かれている通り、`pandas.concat()` を使います。この引数としては結合したい DataFrame を全てリストに入れて呼び出す形をとりますので、ループの中では単にリストへの追加を行い、ループの外で１回呼び出すと良いかとおもいます。