# awkで複数ファイルの入力(指定)にアスタリスクが使えますか？

Tags: windows, awk

①引数は1ファイル(最初のファイル?)だけですか。仕様ページを教えて下さい。
②*.csvから、「data1a2.csv data1a3.csv ......」簡単に引数(ファイル名の羅列)を作る方法を教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

(参考)[pandasで複数のCSVから特定行のみを抽出してCSVにしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49179/pandas%e3%81%a7%e8%a4%87%e6%95%b0%e3%81%aecsv%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e7%89%b9%e5%ae%9a%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%ae%e3%81%bf%e3%82%92%e6%8a%bd%e5%87%ba%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6csv%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

```
rem gawk "NR==1" data1a1.csv >  output.csv
rem gawk "NR==2" *.csv       >> output.csv
gawk "NR==1" data1a1.csv >  output.csv
gawk "NR==2" data1a2.csv >> output.csv
gawk "NR==2" data1a3.csv >> output.csv
```

2018-10-15----------------------------------------------------------------

> 実行環境
>   win7+gawk3.1.5

Comment: `NR` ではなく `FNR` を使うべきでしょうね。`gawk 'FNR==2' *.csv >> output.csv`

Comment: `rem` があることを見ると、`cmd.exe` の話なのかなと思いますが、実行環境を質問に含めた方が確実かと思います。

Comment: 複数ファイルが引数に指定されていればそれらのリストを順に処理するはずですが、`*`を展開するのは`awk`ではなくシェルの役目になるので、mjyさんが仰る通り実行環境も記載してもらった方がよいかと。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cubickさんがコメントされていますが、`*.csv`を展開するのは一般的には呼び出し側のシェルの役目です。そのため呼び出されたプログラム側（今回では`gawk`）には既に展開済みのファイル名を受け取ります。

ただし、Windowsのみ状況が異なります。Windowsでは`*.csv`を展開するのは呼び出されたプログラム側の役目となります。つまり`gawk`が`*.csv`をどのように扱うかに委ねられます。

結局、gawk 3.1.5がどのような設定でコンパイルされたかに依存します。ですのでgawk 3.1.5の入手元に尋ねるほかありません。なお、gawk 3.1.5は2005/07リリースとのことであまりに古く回答が得られるか怪しいです。
軽くググったところ[gawk 3.1.5 for Windows](https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/win95/util/se376460.html)がヒットしましたがこれの場合

> GNU awk 3.1.5 の Windows版です。双方向パイプ、Internet対応を含めWindows用に改変して動作するようにしています。

とあるようにgawkが改変されているようで、[公開されているリポジトリ](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git)そのままではないようです。他の方が作成されたものであっても同様に事が予想されます。